# Understanding the double negation modality under the "propositions as types" paradigm

Tags: topos-theory, type-theory, infinity-topos-theory, homotopy-type-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$I'm trying to understand the double negation modality under the "propositions as types" paradigm, but I'm running into an apparent contradiction: let $T$ be a type in an arbitrary $\infty$-topos $\mathcal{U}$, which, for this question, we might assume to be $(-1)$-truncated and encoding the truth value of some proposition $p$ in $\mathcal{U}$. Let us assume furthermore that $T$ contains a non-trivial sub-singleton (a morphism $\iota:s\hookrightarrow T$ exists for $s\hookrightarrow *$ that does not extend to a morphism $\overline{\iota}:*\rightarrow T$). As I understand it, $s$ encodes the truth of $\neg\neg p$ in that, since $T$ is not completely empty, $\neg T = \Hom(T,\emptyset)$ is empty, so that $\neg\neg T = \Hom(\neg T, \emptyset)$ contains exactly the identity, so that $\neg\neg p$ is true. Applying then the double negation modality to $T$ maps it to $\neg\neg T\simeq *$.

However, as I understand it, externally the double negation operator is the composition of the global sections functor of $\mathcal{U}$ with its right adjoint (see, for instance, under Proposition 1.25 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Science+of+Logic#TheGround which is where I stumbled upon the question). But, since $T$ contains no global constituent $*\rightarrow T$, this would mean that $T$ would be mapped to $\emptyset$. Now, I'm sure my understanding is wrong in some (possibly fundamental) regard. Can someone help me see the error of my ways?

Edit: As was pointed out by Simon Henry, the internal $\Hom$ from a sub-singleton to $\emptyset$ does not have to be empty. For instance, the presheaf topos on a topological space contains as sub-singletons the open sets and their negation is the interior of their complement, which generally does not span the whole space, so a partially defined morphism from the complement of the negation to the empty space exists. It is only that the internal $\Hom$ cannot have any global points in such a case.

Comment: Proposition 1.25 does not say that $Hom(Hom(-,\emptyset),\emptyset)$ is the composite of the global sections functor with its right adjoint. It says that algebras for the monad given by the composite of that right adjoint with the global sections functor is a Boolean topos, which is an entirely different statement.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე This may just be my stupidity, but I still don't get it. In https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sharp+modality, they explicitly say that the $\sharp$-modality, which they identify on the page I linked to above with double negation, is the composition of $\Gamma$ with its right adjoint. Later on the "Science of Logic"-page (under "Quantity"), they say that the objects for which $T\rightarrow\sharp T$ is a monomorphism are purely determined by their point content. How do you arrive at the category of algebras?

Comment: Containing a non-trivial subsingleton is not enough to obtain $\neg \neg p$. It seems you are confusing the internal hom, for which $\neg p = Hom(p,\varnothing)$ and the external which will be empty if p is not the proposition false.

Comment: They say that the sharp modality is $\operatorname{loc}_{\neg\neg}$. This is not $\neg\neg$, it is something different.

Comment: Maybe this helps: morphisms $*\to\operatorname{loc}_{\neg\neg}T$ "are" morphisms $s\to T$, where $s\hookrightarrow*$ satisfies $Hom(s,\emptyset)=\emptyset$ (*internal* hom, as Simon pointed out above). To make that "are" more rigorous you have to count $s\to T$ and $s'\to T$ as "the same" if one is an extension of the other. Unfortunately even then this is not entirely rigorous.